# Why do clients echo webserver's message back to it?

Tags: c, linux, sockets, http, server

I've made a simple linux socket webserver and watched its http traffic. Frequently, when it sends a HTTP 200 or 404 back to a requesting GET or POST client (web browser or scanner), the client echoes back the message just sent by the server back to it. Why do they behave like that and what answer do they expect from my server?

> > > new connection 0 established with 37.236.190.20:39889
> > >
> > > new message 0 received from 37.236.190.20:39889
> > >
> > > GET / HTTP/1.1
> > >       Connection: Keep-Alive                                                       Keep-Alive: 300
> > >       User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHT
> > >       ML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.132 Safari/537.36
> > >       Host: 18.231.188.211
> > >
> > > sent file login.html to 0 37.236.190.20:39889 successfully | nsent = 550
> > >
> > > new message 0 received from 37.236.190.20:39889
> > >
> > > HTTP/1.1 200 OK
> > >       Connection: close
> > >       Content-Length: 465
> > >       Content-Type: text/html
> > >
> > > [html page I sent here]
> > >
> > > sent file login.html to 0 37.236.190.20:39889 successfully | nsent = 550
> > >
> > > connection 0 with 37.236.190.20:39889 was forcebly closed. cause: echoing

Comment: Interesting, what are you coding your webserver in? what are you using for your network connection?

Comment: It's in C with linux sockets

Comment: Okay. I added in the relevant tags so people can help you. Can you also edit in the code you use to respond and send the data? I think then you stand a chance to get an answer from someone who is knowledgeable about this subject. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Check if you are not responding to yourself!

Comment: @MartinMeeser almost that lol

Comment: @Tschallacka thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I wasn't finding any record of such behavior anywhere, with the help of gdb I found out that I was using an unsigned variable to hold the return value of a function that on error returns -1.

```
msg_buffer.length = recv(connected[i].socket, msg_buffer.data, msg_buffer.size, 0);
if (msg_buffer.length < 0) { // no message
```

So the evaluation in the second line would never be true and the length of the message would be 0xffffffffffffffff. But since the buffer held my previously sent message and no new message was received to overwrite that, it appeared that the clients were echoing my server.
Thank you all for the help. And sorry for the mistake.